# How can I insert an image in a SVG placeholder?

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-5

This is all new stuff to me. I'm trying to use Bootstrap template name "Carousel" as my base. I'm using Bootstrap 5.3.2.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/

All good so far. But i can't find any documentation on how to have my personal rounded image in the SVG placeholder instead of that gray filling.

Any help please? I would like to have an image to replace that gray SVG round placeholder.

```
<svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
        <title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
```

[image: Bootstrap Template screenshot]

Comment: Replace the svg placeholder with an image tag and add the same Bootstrap classes to make it round.  See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/n0ej1mha/show)

Comment: @Yogi thanks! Easy solution! You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for Bootstrap, wrap it in a *native* Web Component:

```js
customElements.define("svg-avatar", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let id   = "id" + crypto.randomUUID();
    let href = "https://octodex.github.com/images/" + this.getAttribute("src");
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    this.innerHTML     = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="${id}" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image href="${href}" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"/>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <circle fill="url(#${id})" cx="50" cy="50" r="49" stroke="black"/>`;
  }
});
```

```css
svg-avatar {
  width: 180px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<svg-avatar src="original.jpg"></svg-avatar>
<svg-avatar src="saint_nictocat.jpg"></svg-avatar>
<svg-avatar src="grinchtocat.gif"></svg-avatar>
```

Answer (score 0):

svg files support **image tag** to embed images within svg files:

```
<svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Embedding an image -->
 <image xlink:href="PATH_TO_YOUR_IMG.png" width="400" height="300" />
</svg>
```